# Unique checking constraint in Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, unique, unique-constraint

There are unique indexes that I use. I want to check if these unique indexes exist at the time of posting

> Entity Framework Core: Npgsql.PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint.

This is the error I was expecting anyway. But how can I check it without getting this error ?